# I need to complete a column with a value based on other columns

Tags: sharepoint-server, team-sites

I am trying to setup a Service Desk ticketing system using the Issue tracking facility. On the form I have an *Urgency* (Low, Medium, High, Critical) field and an *Impact* (Individual, Team, Department, Organisation) field.

I would like to populate a Priority field based on a matrix of the 2., i.e., Low+Individual=P4 , High+Organisation=P1

Any ideas how I can do this? I am aware there is a calculated field option but am unsure as to the formula syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could use a calculated column for this, and you'd have to use many levels of nested If/Then statements to make it work.  For example it might look like this, with nested IF's and AND statements:

```
IF(AND([Urgency]="Low",[Impact]="Individual"),"P1",
    IF(AND([Urgency]="Low",[Impact]="Team"),"P2",
        IF(AND([Urgency]="Low",[Impact]="Department"),"P3",
            IF(AND([Urgency]="Low",[Impact]="Organization"),"P4",
                ...etc
```

But maybe your matrix combines a few conditions such that Low Urgency AND (Team OR Department Impact) would be a priority 2.  In that case you'd have to nest in an OR clause with 2 or more comparisons like below (in the second line):

```
IF(AND([Urgency]="Low",[Impact]="Individual"),"P1",
    IF(AND([Urgency]="Low",OR([Impact]="Team",[Impact]="Department")),"P2",
        IF(AND([Urgency]="Low",[Impact]="Organization"),"P4",
            ...etc
```

You can keep adding clauses to the OR statement, so you could say 'If Urgency is High and Impact is Team, Department, or Organization, priority is 4:

```
IF(AND([Urgency]="Low",OR([Impact]="Team",[Impact]="Department",[Impact]="Organization")),"P4")
```